# Insert tag a right after img

Tags: html, image

Have look on this code:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge"><?=$st ?></span>
    <img class="small_profile_pic" src="<?=$pic ?>" /> aaa<a href="#"><?=$msg['UserName'] ?></a> :
</a>
```

this is a row that show a message in short type. in this row I need to `<a href="#"><?=$msg['UserName'] ?></a>` be after image but it going to next line.
when I type word without a tag its OK but links goes to next line. How do I fix this?

more explanation on this pic:
[image: Look at this pic]

Please notice that I can't use `float`, if there is another way except `float` please tell me that.

## Edited:

(I have fixed that place by changing parent tag to span but ...)
I need to make whole row a link to that specific message and make username a link to user profile. Who can I place links inside each other?Or another solution maybe?

## Second Edit

I have placed a tags inside each other and both of them works well but still second a tag goes to next line! I have tried `display:inline` but whole row collapsed!

Comment: You can't put `a` tag inside another `a` tag

Comment: Ah, yes I missed that parent a tag, I have change it to span an it fixes. Thank you bro.

Comment: but another question is there any way to make whole row a link and that username be another link?

Comment: You can use `a` tag as parent.

Comment: Yes, but that second a tag goes to next line!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 'a' tag in "a" tag .... but just for you If you want to align it after image use style property and use ,

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <span class="badge"><?=$st ?></span>
    <img class="small_profile_pic" src="<?=$pic ?>" style="display:inline" /> aaa<a href="#" style="display:inline"><?=$msg['UserName'] ?></a> :
</a>
```